# Comparing fields from two models using foreign key.(for displaying correct product under correct category) using django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, jinja2

I have two models Category and Product. Here is **models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Product(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    productid=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    disimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.productid
```

In my template I have two for loops the outer one that iterates category model and the other that iterates through products and i want to display the product only if the category.type is equal to the product category (for example if there is a type=Shirt in category then I want display a product under it only if it has type=Shirt )

Here is my **HTML**

```
{% for i in types %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row product-btn d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                <!-- Section Tittle -->
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-5">

                    <div class="section-tittle mb-30" id="{{i.type}}">
                        <h2>{{i.type}}</h2>
                    </div>


                </div>

                
            </div>
                          <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

                <!-- card one -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        {% for product in prods %}

                        {% if i.type == product.category %}
                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                            <div class="single-product mb-60">


                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img src="{{product.disimage.url}}" alt="">

                                </div>
                                <div class="product-caption">

                                    <h4><a href="#" id="{{product.productid}}">{{product.name}}</a></h4>
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>RS {{product.currentprice}}</li>
                                            <li class="discount">RS {{product.originalprice}}</li>
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="/category/singleproduct/{{product.productid}}" class="btn header-btn btn-outline-info">View</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn header-btn btn-outline-info">Add to Cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I am trying to do this using {% if i.type == product.category %} but i am not succeeding. Any help on how to work this out will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the following

```
{% if i.type == product.category.type %}
```

Comment: its ok. happens. :) take a break and start again. helps a lot